SVG icon not visible
I don't know what could be the problem with the SVG code below. It is not displayed in the browser, but it looks nice when displayed directly. If I replace them in the CSS with any other SVG, they all show up.
ul.custom li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="23" height="23" fill="none"><g fill="#CC902D" clip-path="url(#a)"><path d="M10.748 16.251a.65.65 0 0 1-.461-.191l-4.53-4.54a.652.652 0 0 1 0-.922l2.165-2.165a.652.652 0 0 1 .46-.19h.001a.65.65 0 0 1 .461.191l1.905 1.913 3.408-3.408a.652.652 0 0 1 .921 0l2.165 2.165a.652.652 0 0 1 0 .921l-6.035 6.036a.651.651 0 0 1-.46.19Zm-3.61-5.191 3.61 3.618 5.114-5.113-1.244-1.244-3.41 3.41a.652.652 0 0 1-.46.19h-.001a.65.65 0 0 1-.461-.191L8.38 9.816 7.138 11.06Z"/><path d="M22.349 23H.65A.651.651 0 0 1 0 22.349V.65C0 .291.292 0 .651 0h21.697c.36 0 .652.292.652.651v17.302a.651.651 0 1 1-1.303 0V1.303H1.303v20.394h21.045a.651.651 0 1 1 0 1.303Z"/><path d="M19.184 19.836H3.815a.651.651 0 0 1-.651-.651V6.929a.651.651 0 1 1 1.303 0v11.604h14.066V4.467H3.815a.651.651 0 1 1 0-1.303h15.37c.36 0 .65.292.65.652v15.369c0 .36-.29.651-.65.651Z"/></g><defs><clipPath id="a"><path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h23v23H0z"/></clipPath></defs></svg>');
}


You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

A couple of tips: use your browser devtools inspect facility to find where that pseudo element is (as it’s positioned absolute, what is that relative to?) and note that double colons are used in CSS now to distinguish pseudo elements from pseudo classes.

I have tried your code, but most probably you are missing to include position: relative; to the ul.custom li:
ul.custom li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px; /*  some padding to text */
}



ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.custom li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;/*  some padding to text */
}

ul.custom li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="23" height="23" fill="none"><g fill="%23CC902D" clip-path="url(%23a)"><path d="M10.748 16.251a.65.65 0 0 1-.461-.191l-4.53-4.54a.652.652 0 0 1 0-.922l2.165-2.165a.652.652 0 0 1 .46-.19h.001a.65.65 0 0 1 .461.191l1.905 1.913 3.408-3.408a.652.652 0 0 1 .921 0l2.165 2.165a.652.652 0 0 1 0 .921l-6.035 6.036a.651.651 0 0 1-.46.19Zm-3.61-5.191 3.61 3.618 5.114-5.113-1.244-1.244-3.41 3.41a.652.652 0 0 1-.46.19h-.001a.65.65 0 0 1-.461-.191L8.38 9.816 7.138 11.06Z"/><path d="M22.349 23H.65A.651.651 0 0 1 0 22.349V.65C0 .291.292 0 .651 0h21.697c.36 0 .652.292.652.651v17.302a.651.651 0 1 1-1.303 0V1.303H1.303v20.394h21.045a.651.651 0 1 1 0 1.303Z"/><path d="M19.184 19.836H3.815a.651.651 0 0 1-.651-.651V6.929a.651.651 0 1 1 1.303 0v11.604h14.066V4.467H3.815a.651.651 0 1 1 0-1.303h15.37c.36 0 .65.292.65.652v15.369c0 .36-.29.651-.65.651Z"/></g><defs><clipPath id="a"><path fill="%23fff" d="M0 0h23v23H0z"/></clipPath></defs></svg>');
}
<ul class="custom">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>




This is not the problem, because then other SVGs would not be displayed correctly. But thanks for the working code, it helped me narrow down my troubleshooting. It was solved, # had to be coded with %23.

You may accept the answer if it solved your problem, so others would not spend time to work on it. Best.

This is closed question, no others work on it. It is not currently accepting answers.

Oh, I realize that now.
